# Adding constraint to the "main view" in a xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, xib

I have a `UIView` defined in a .xib file. I need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO`. This means that the frame is not translated to constraints so I need to set the size constraints by myself.

I have created a working category method for a `UIView`:

```
-(NSArray*)setSizeConstraints:(CGSize)size
{
    NSLayoutConstraint* height = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:0 toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1  constant:size.height];
    NSLayoutConstraint* width = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:0 toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1  constant:size.width];

    [self addConstraint:height];
    [self addConstraint:width];

    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:height, width, nil];
}
```

But I would like to set these constraints from the Xcode interface builder, but all my AutoLayout controls are greyed out:
[image: Xcode interface builder]

Is there a way to do this in the interface builder?

Answer (score 2):

### This actually is possible.

Simply put the view you'd like to constrain into another view, like the highlighted view here.
[image]

Then, add your desired constraints.

Finally, pull the view you just added constraints to **out** of its parent view. You can now add constraints to that view.

[image]

Comment: Can you really do this with the _main view_? Putting the main view in another view creates a copy and I dont see any way to set the copied view as the main view again.

Answer (score 0):

As you've surely found out by now, it looks like there's currently no way to set Autolayout constraints at the main `UIView` level from Interface Builder.

I had a similar problem here ([Launch Screen XIB: Missing Width / Height Constraints (Xcode 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219842/launch-screen-xib-missing-width-height-constraints)), while working with the launch screen of my app.

The only workarounds I found, if you want to keep working with IB, are:

- Using a `UIViewController` and its `UIView` inside the XIB, instead of just a `UIView`
- Working only with Storyboards (and, once again, `UIViewController`)

However, I understand these approaches may not be ideal or "clean", especially if you simply have a subclass of `UIView` and you want to draw its interface in a good old XIB.